# Should i use peer block to better secure my computer?

Tags: network, ip, internet

Should i be using [peer block](http://www.peerblock.com/) to secure my computer or is there a better way to accomplish the same task?

I dont file share, my curiosity of peer block came from my research of security of my computer. I saw peerblock a great way to control the connections coming into my computer. I found plenty of block lists and also went as far as creating a white list. Not only have i seen improvements in cpu usage but peerblock is telling me its blocking some pretty suspicious IPs. Some IP address names that come up on peer block are "private use networks", "bogon", and sometimes some random companies. I recently added another list and one ip that has frightened me which i will not disclose has popped up a few times. This is a strictly get work done computer where i also store personal pictures and videos. With the recent development of computer being hacked and set for random or other malicious situations security is always on my mind.

What do all these blocked IPs mean? Am i securing my computer? Is there a better way to secure my computer? Should i be using peerblock? Can peer block protect me from malware or being hacked? Provided that i white list connections that update software, am i hurting myself by using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should i use peer block to better secure my computer?

This would not increase your security in a dramatic way. PeerBlock was not intended to protect your computer from attack, only attempt to block as they claim "known bad guys" in p2p networks. They do not market the technology as a way to control or supplement firewall deny rules. Rotating or acquiring new IP addresses, proxying traffic, or spoofing IP addresses is low effort. Playing "whack a mole" with blocking IP addresses is not normally considered an efficient way to secure a host or network.

Try these in SuperUser:

[How to secure Windows 7 computer](https://superuser.com/questions/222080/how-to-secure-my-windows-7-pc)

[How to properly secure Linux computer](https://superuser.com/questions/273916/how-to-properly-secure-a-linux-computer)

[Secure Mac OSX purchased from a stranger](https://superuser.com/questions/498741/how-can-i-secure-a-mac-purchased-from-a-stranger)

Answer (score 2):

> What do all these blocked IPs mean?

The fact that those IP addresses are being blocked or a suspicious IP address tries to send packet to your network, does not mean that you computer/network is compromised. The majority of the traffic coming through random IP addresses are either noise (misconfiguration on internet hosts) or automated malicious bots. Unless your computer is running ancient broken software or exposed a network service to Internet with a weak password, most these automated attacks are ineffective.

Remember, if you are behind a NAT (home router) your computer open ports is only accessible to your home network and not outside world (assuming you don't have port forwarding enabled).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I keep software and operating system up to date. So what you are saying is that peerblock is useless in my case.  I see peerblock as an extra layer to the firewall for my comp blocking some known malicious malware or spyware servers. But what it seems like you are saying is that i dont need to worry about it as my computer is up to date and not infected?

Comment: Couldnt peerblock be another layer of the firewall? A preventative measure for malicious servers or hackers that find vulnerabilities in software. There are many block lists for known malicious malware servers and prevent communication from harmful remote servers because of vulnerable software or hacking.

Comment: I'm not really sure you answered the question Dr.

Comment: He answered one of the questions included, I expanded in a second answer for the title's question to help.

Comment: @user26409 I do not see it improving security much at all. You are better served investing time in running noscript extensions or disabling flash, as well as practicing safer routines to check for malware and viruses. Follow some of my linked guidance for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, peerblock is a EXCELLENT way to secure your computer, especially if you are not looking to spend every moment that you sit at it fussing with security.  I am a Network Administrator and a Home Repair Technician, and I have been using a combo of Peerblock and Panda Cloud Free Antivirus for 10+ years.  I have had phenomenal results.  The re-infection rate of my clients was about 80% because none of them changed what they were doing.  Once I installed those two programs... only one client ever got a computer infection again, and that was only under EXTREME circumstances.  Like you, I discovered by accident that Peerblock was constantly blocking IPs from the moment of Windows installation, (which explains how you can get a virus 30 seconds after first boot from the Microsoft website)!  You are actually the first person I've come across to have discovered it the way I did.  Cheers.